# Why do some WinAPI functions need sizes of structs passed as their parameters?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

For example, consider `SendInput`. The signature looks like this:

```
UINT WINAPI SendInput(
  _In_ UINT    nInputs,
  _In_ LPINPUT pInputs,
  _In_ int     cbSize
);
```

The documentation says:

> cbSize [in] Type: int The size, in bytes, of an INPUT structure. If
>   cbSize is not the size of an INPUT structure, the function fails.

Since the function already uses the INPUT structure (and probably does something with its various fields), shouldn't it be aware of the structure's size beforehand?

The only reason I can imagine is that this is some kind of odd backwards-compatibility trick to make older library binaries compatible with newer header files that may have introduced new fields at the end of the struct.

Comment: Yes, this allows for the evolution of the structure. This way, members could be added to the structure later, but the implementation can still work for older clients that didn't know about them. As one example I happen to remember off the top, see `OPENFILENAME`, and in particular the mention of `OPENFILENAME_SIZE_VERSION_400` in the documentation.

Comment: Another example involves the [`RegisterClassEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx) function and the associated [`WNDCLASSEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx) type. With the original `RegisterClass` function, you can't set the small icon of the window. Also, `WNDCLASS` has no `cbSize` member, so you can't mix `RegisterClass` and `WNDCLASSEX` or `RegisterClassEx` and `WNDCLASS` safely. The `cbSize` member is a way to correct this in future API versions to avoid creating a `RegisterClassEx2` function.

Comment: This is worst question, what I see, -1

Comment: @Xearinox, what is so bad about my question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a simple form of versioning for the structures.

A later version of the API could add more fields to the end of the structure, which would change its size.  Programs written for the older version won't have set values in the newer fields and the cbSize parameter will reflect that.  That API can check cbSize and know which version of the structure it really has, and, if necessary, provide default values for the new fields.

The alternative would be to define a new structure that has a lot in common with the old structure, and then make a new API that works a lot like the old one.  That's a lot of code duplication, and it makes it harder for older programs to be recompiled using a newer SDK and continue to work.

Using a size field eliminates the need for a bunch of duplicate code.  It was a common way to do things in C, but it's less type-safe.

But it's also a little dangerous.  If the caller doesn't set the size field correctly or if the API implementation isn't very careful, this scheme could lead to access violations, reading of uninitialized fields, or writing past the end of a the structure.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is done so Microsoft can change the INPUT structure in a future version of winapi.  From the passed cbSize, it can tell whether the program uses the old or the new version of the structure.  This is not otherwise easy to discover from the structure itself.

Passing it as an argument to the function isn't that common, they usually embed `cbSize` as a member of the structure.  Compare to [WNDCLASSEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), MENUITEMINFO, SCROLLINFO, MSGBOXPARAMS for example.  It is just easier to do it with a single argument for functions like SendInput() and GetMouseMovePointsEx() because they take arrays of structures.

Another approach is taken for structures like [LVITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), LVCOLUMN, etcetera, they don't use a cbSize at all.  Using their api requires specifying the desired version explicitly in [a manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_manifests).

Comment: It is a separate parameter because you are passing an array of structures, and it would be annoying to have initialize the size member of every structure (and what if the sizes don't all agree?)